# New To JavaScript, Need Correction: Making 2 Button Change 2 Different Texts

Tags: javascript

Ok, so i am quite new to JavaScript, and may not know what i am doing wrong, so i need help correcting any mistakes i've made.  My aim to to make a title, and a sentence with 2 buttons.  One button is supposed to change the text of the sentence, and the other to change the text of the title.

Here's my thoughts:  I named the functions title and sentence (If i did it right) so when i click the button that is said to execute that command on click, it does. (obviously)  So like onclick="title()"  I mean when you click that button, it runs the code that would change the title, and vice versa for the sentence.  All i end up getting when i open it is 2 buttons, a sentence, and a title.  I click the buttons, nothing happens.  So my question is;  How do i make 2 buttons that change 2 different entities.  One to change title, one to change the sentence.  Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Title() {
 document.getElementById=("demo").innerHTML = "Title Changed"
}
function Sentence() {
     document.getElementById=("demo").innerHTML = "Sentence Changed"
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="demo">The Title</h1>

<p1 id="demo">The Sentence</p1>

<button type="button" onclick="Title()">Title Button</button>

<button type="button" onclick="Sentence()">Sentence Button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique — browser behaviour for non-unique IDs is technically undefined. You will have to use different IDs for your H1 and paragraph elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is most of the way there, but you need to understand that in HTML the `id` attribute is like a street address: it does not make sense to give two different buildings the exact same address. So the value of every `id` attribute on a page should be unique.

Also, there is no such tag as `p1` in HTML5, so you should change this to the standard paragraph element `p`.

Finally, `getElementById` is a function call, so there is no `=` between the function name and its argument `("title")` so the equals sign needs to be removed.

Combined, your code should look like this:

```html
<h1 id="title">The Title</h1>
<p id="sentence">The Sentence</p>
```

and this:

```js
function Title() {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Title Changed";
}
function Sentence() {
    document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = "Sentence Changed";
}
```

Your JavaScript should then be targeting the correct elements and you should see the content change when each button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

- ID's should be unique (use different ID's for title and sentence).
- `document.getElementById=("demo")` is just wrong syntax... There should be no assignment operator in between.
- There's no such tag as `p1`.

```js
function Title() {
 document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Title Changed";
}
function Sentence() {
  document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = "Sentence Changed";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">The Title</h1>

<p id="sentence">The Sentence</p>

<button type="button" onclick="Title()">Title Button</button>

<button type="button" onclick="Sentence()">Sentence Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique on html page. Code corrected as per your need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Title() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Title Changed";
}
function Sentence() {
     document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = "Sentence Changed";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="demo">The Title</h1>

<p1 id="sentence">The Sentence</p1>

<button type="button" onclick="Title()">Title Button</button>

<button type="button" onclick="Sentence()">Sentence Button</button>

</body>
</html>
```